# Redux Saga API is being called twice yet the action is dispatched only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, saga

I have this sign up button, which takes the form data as payload and dispatch the API, the strange thing is the action is only dispatched once but in saga the API is called twice, which in turns sends 2 sign up requests and generates error.
Following is code which is responsible for dispatching action

```
export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onSignIn: (data) => {
      dispatch(signInUser(data));
    },
    makeCreateUser: (data, countryName, signupFields) => {
      dispatch(createUser(data, countryName, signupFields));
    }
  };
}
```

Following is the action

```
export function createUser(data, countryName, signupFields) {  
  return {
    type: CREATE_USER,
    data,
    countryName,
    signupFields,
  };
}
```

Following is reducer

```
case CREATE_USER:
  return state
    .set('userSuccess', false)
    .set('userError', false);
case CREATE_USER_SUCCESS:
  return state
    .set('userSuccess', action.response);
case CREATE_USER_ERROR:
  return state
    .set('userError', action.error);
```

Following code calls the API in saga

```
// CREATE_USER
export function* createUser(payload) {
  const requestURL = `users/signup${window.location.search}`;

  try {
      // Call our request helper (see 'utils/request')
    const response = yield call(request, requestURL, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(payload.data) });
    yield put(signInUserSuccess(response, payload.data.provider, payload.signupFields, true));
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(createUserError(err, payload));
  }
}
export default function* AccountSagas() {
     yield takeLatest(CREATE_USER, createUser);
}
```

Following is the definition for signInUserSuccess, sendSignUpFormEvent is for analytics

```
export function signInUserSuccess(response, provider = null, 

signupFields = null, isNewUser = false) {
  segmentIdentity(response.user);
  storage.setItem(USER_KEY, response.user);
  eraseCookie('xiangqi.jwt_token'); // just making sure to remove previous cookie;
  setCookie('xiangqi.jwt_token', response.access_token, 10);
  if (isNewUser) {
    sendSignUpFormEvent(response.user, {
      provider,
      errorFields: null,
      errorType: null,
      isSuccessful: true,
      signupFields,
    });
  } else {
    sendSignInFormEvent(response.user, provider);
  }
  return {
    type: SIGN_IN_USER_SUCCESS,
    response,
  };
}
```

Please have a look at createUser in codebase, its only being used once as generator

[image]

Also I added logs on the whole request journey and as you can see in the picture the API is being called twice from saga.js

[image]

Comment: What is the definition for `signInUserSuccess`

Comment: @ChadS. I have edited the question and added the definition please have a look thanks

Comment: Will need to see how `*createUser` is connected to redux store, I guess it's installed twice somehow.

Comment: Can you show your root saga? (and any intermediary sagas) it looks like you have two different sagas watching for the CREATE_USER action.

Comment: @hackape I don't quite understand what you are asking for

Comment: @ChadS. I have confirmed CREATE_USER action is being watched by only this saga thats all

Comment: @Cinya I meant the same as what Chad S. suspected. Well if you're so sure that multiple watch/installation is not the cause, then I'm out of ideas. I suggest put a `debugger` statement inside `*createUser` and start backtracing the call stack to find out where it originates.

Comment: @hackape i have one update on this and it might be the key, scenario was when I changed language and signed up to some account, I made some changes in code to check I remove the yield takeLatest(CREATE_USER, createUser); from Account saga, I signed out and signed up again and there was no repetitive calls yet the sign up worked perfectly fine and i did this multiple times, but when i reloaded obviously the sign up call did not triggered, It seems like redux saga has cached the API's, is there anyway this can be avoided?

Comment: I don't know what's happening on your screen. Key info is missing in your post, and your description isn't helpful. "Is there anyway this can be avoided" I believe yes it can, if we find out the root cause. But obvious we cannot proceed with given info thus far. Share more useful code.

Comment: I stand by my previous judgement, it's because multiple installation of `createUser`. Why don't you run a full codebase search for `createUser` and show us where it's been used? I mean the `createUser` the generator function, not the action creator function of the same name.

Comment: @hackape alright sure, please see the attached screenshot for full code base search of createUser as you can see there is only one generator function

Comment: Then how is `AccountSagas` used? Because `createUser` is wrapped inside.

Comment: Also, put a debugger breakpoint inside `createUser`, reproduce the double firing behavior and show us the call stack in devtool. I expect the two API call’s call stack to be different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248102/discussion-between-cinya-and-hackape).